# SPA authentication using sanctum failed with this error message: "Unauthenticated."

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I am building SPA with Vuejs and Laravel, I installed the laravel sanctum to authenticate the user by its token.

Api.php

```
Route::post('/teacher/login', 'Teacher\RegisterController@login')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Login.Vue

```
login(){
            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                this.form.post('api/teacher/login')
                .then( response => {
                    console.log( response );
                })
                .catch( error => {
                    console.log( error );
                })
            });
        }
```

Custom Controller

```
public function login(Request $request){

$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
        }
}
```

I checked this without sanctum middleware it successfully logging the user, but I add the middleware inside the route it says your request is Unauthenticated.
I implemented everything by following the official Laravel-7 doc, I don't why it says Unauthenticated, attaching the IMG for more detail.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share `csrf-cookie` response? And the list of all cookies?

Comment: Sure, I attached the application cookie shot, please have a look on it.

Comment: @Harun R Rayhan Is there any issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. 

Make sure the X-CSRF-TOKEN or X-XSRF-TOKEN you gotten from `csrf-cookie` is appended to the HTTP request header to `api/teacher/login`. For Axios, you can set it with

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = <the x-xsrf-token from csrf-cookie request>
```

2. 

Make sure to declare `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` in `.env` with the port number.
You can include multiple domain with it as well.
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='your-domain.test:8080,localhost:8000'

Without this you will encounter `Session store not set` issue due to middleware `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` is checking whether the request is from frontend or not. If it is from fronetned, then it will attach following middlewares to it

- EncryptCookies
- StartSession
- VerifyCsrfToken

Comment: I added this line globally in bootstrap.js window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; also added stateful domains, but it did not work

Comment: X-Requested-With is for CORS request checking, so you still need to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN, which will be sent on each request you made subsequently to fulfill the CSRF requirement by Laravel

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more, how can I fix this issue.